# Symfony Propel Integration

Tags: symfony, reverse-engineering, propel

im have installed PropelBundle (1.2.0) for Symfnoy 2.3.
I set the configuration files as:

**config.yml**

```
propel:
    path: "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/propel"
    phing_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/phing"
```

**config_*.yml**

```
propel:
    dbal:
        driver: %database_driver%
        user: %database_user%
        password: %database_password%
        dsn: %database_driver%:host=%database_host%;dbname=%database_name%;%database_charset%
        options: {}
        attributes: {}
```

**parameters.yml**

```
parameters:
    database_driver: mysql
    database_host: 127.0.0.1
    database_port: null
    database_name: xxxxxxxxx
    database_user: xxxxxxxxx
    database_password: xxxxxxxxxxx
    database_charset: UTF8
    mailer_transport: smtp
    mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
    mailer_user: null
    mailer_password: null
    locale: en
    secret: ThisTokenIsNotSoSecretChangeIt
```

And when i try execute the propel reverse engineering with:

> rama@rastrojero:/var/www/AppManantiales$ php app/console
>   propel:reverse

The console returns:

```
Use connection named default in dev environment.
No generated files.
```

Any ideas ?

Edit: I install PropelBundle from Composer.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is highly localised to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

The database passsword was wrong. Thanks !